# Oracle ANSI Join - Is Comment on Off-Topic Theme On-Topic?

Tags: discussion, comments, scope

Practically every question that uses the *classical* Oracle join syntax (comma separated tables, join condition in the WHERE clause and (+) for outer join) as an example is subject of comments pointing out toward the usage of ANSI join syntax.

A few examples of such comments randomly selected with search on keywords  "archaic join syntax", "modern ANSI join syntax" and similar are listed below:

[Joins in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484187/joins-in-oracle/56484348#comment99558677_56484187)

[Create a view and should not allow any data manipulation language operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65426315/create-a-view-and-should-not-allow-any-data-manipulation-language-operations#comment115670939_65426315)

[Select Max date column in a sql query, which is joined to other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60763527/select-max-date-column-in-a-sql-query-which-is-joined-to-other-columns#comment107507547_60763527)

[Column ambiguously defined error. Working without pagination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733310/column-ambiguously-defined-error-working-without-pagination#comment90427649_51733310)

[MySQL Error with SELECT * FROM (SELECT *...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44022184/mysql-error-with-select-from-select#comment75070989_44022184)

[extractValue and right outer join - Oracle SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818165/extractvalue-and-right-outer-join-oracle-sql#comment17337176_12818165)

[Joins in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484187/joins-in-oracle/56484348#comment99558743_56484187)

My understanding is that such comments are not compatible with the [on-topic policy](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - even they are *comments* only and not *questions*. Such comments should be therefore processed based on the above mentioned policy i.e. should be *removed*.

Let me give some argumentation for my claim.

### Opinion Based

Even that there are some questions concerning the usage of ASNI Join syntax on SO

[Oracle Joins - Comparison between conventional syntax VS ANSI Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18891148/oracle-joins-comparison-between-conventional-syntax-vs-ansi-syntax)

[What is difference between ANSI and non-ANSI joins, and which do you recommend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19905028/what-is-difference-between-ansi-and-non-ansi-joins-and-which-do-you-recommend)

[Explicit JOINs vs Implicit joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53061517/explicit-joins-vs-implicit-joins)

a question with a title "Should I use Oracle ANSI Join Syntax?" would and should be closed as "opinion based".

And this is for sure an opinion based question. I use the ANSI syntax nearly in all cases, but I respect others that use the *classic* syntax.

There is of course an "official" *opinion* for outer joins from [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Joins.html#GUID-29A4584C-0741-4E6A-A89B-DCFAA222994A).

### Transformation

Oracle uses rather complicated transformation from the ANSI syntax to the internal query form. This can be verified using `DBMS_UTILITY.expand_sql_text` as illustrated [here](https://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/ANSI-Join-Rename-of-Alias-Leads-to-a-Different-Result,1).

The main consequence is that many more query blocks (subqueries) are used than in a manually written equivalent in *Oracle syntax*.

Of course ANSI joins works in recent releases close to perfect, but some bugs are still open e.g. Bug 25342699 : WRONG RESULTS WITH ANSI JOIN USING AND IDENTICAL TABLE ALIASES - see the discussion [here](https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2020/03/18/using-bug/)

### Counterproductive Approach

It should be mentioned, that such good meant hints can be *counterproductive*.

The greatest advantage of ANSI written queries: the clean partitioning of the join conditions, the obvious inner and outer joins and separation of the filter predicates starts shining only in large queries.

The majority of queries in SO questions have two to three tables where the advantage is negligible or even leads to a more verbose syntax.

## Positive Approach

My intention is of course not to suppress the propagation of the Oracle ANSI Join syntax on SO. On contrary this is important mostly above those who never heard about this form of queries.

But this should IMO be done in answers, where the ANSI syntax is used, possibly mentioning the difference and advantages with a point to the documentation link and not in the rather *schoolmasterish* comments.

Is my point and argumentation understandable or do I overlook something?

Comment: Not really @JeanneDark, I do no think a *counter-comment* is appropriate here.

Comment: @JeanneDark That's probably not the right meta, since none of those comments were wrong :) They were correct about it being syntax used prior to 1992 (I think it was 1992 the ANSI standard came out). One can argue that readability was improved by it, which of course is opinionated, however there seems to be a wide consensus of that opinion :)

Comment: I believe they are both ANSI standards. One using the join conditions as part of the WHERE-clause is the ANSI SQL-89, and the other expressing the join condition in an ON clause is the ANSI SQL-92 standard.

Comment: @Scratte not for outer join. ANSI 89 did not have any standard for outer join so there were a load of different proprietary implementations

Comment: @MartinSmith Perhaps that's why it's called the "Oracle (+)"? That never confused me /s :)

Comment: Regarding the Q itself the "on-topic policy" seems irrelevant, You need to find something in the help centre that states the acceptable use of comments. I have no problem with comments pointing out issues such as SQL injection issues but am more ambivalent about more stylistic concerns. Often in SQL Server tags the commenter themselves is confused on the issue and is led to believe that the ANSI 89 **inner** join syntax is itself deprecated.

Comment: Information on the acceptable use of comments can be found on the respective [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment): 1) "Request **clarification** from the author;" 2) "Leave **constructive criticism** that guides the author in improving the post;" 3) "Add relevant but **minor or transient information** to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)."

Comment: Of the 7 questions you chose, 6 are abominable garbage. I feel it's not a coincidence those use non-ANSI join syntax.

Comment: Somehow I feel this is exactly my point @IanKemp, a syntax swap will not improve the quality of those questions, so the comment should trigger in different directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators do not police the technical accuracy or appropriateness of comments. If it looks like the comment is relevant—and these clearly do—then the comments will be preserved, rather than deleted.

The site's ["off topic" rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) don't apply to comments *per se*. (And even if they did, I don't see any way in which those comments would fall afoul of the topicality rules.) Comments are only expected to be relevant to the topic of a particular post. From [the privilege page for commenting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Comments are temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer. They can be upvoted (but not downvoted) and flagged, but do not generate reputation. There's no revision history, and when they are deleted they're gone for good.
>
> […]
>
> You should submit a comment if you want to:
>
> - Request clarification from the author;
> - Leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post;
> - Add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated).

Suggestions on how to improve the code, including a recommendation to use an alternative syntax, fall within the umbrella of "constructive criticism". Therefore, these are valid comments, and should not be deleted by moderators. You should not flag comments simply because you disagree with them.

It's not a problem for comments to state opinions. It's not even a problem for *answers* to state opinions. The only reason we close *questions* for being "primarily opinion-based" is that the *only* possible answers to those question would be opinions, and not even the type of opinions where evidence can be offered to back them up.

If there is a legitimate point to be made in favor of the Oracle or ANSI syntax for a particular type of query, then I would recommend creating a canonical question to document it. Ask a question about the practical reasons why one should be preferred over the other, and then post an answer with a detailed response, containing objective support and/or empirical arguments. From there forward, you could include a link to that Q&A in your comments about the subject.

If you can't think of a way to create a high-quality Q&A on the subject that could serve as a useful, general-purpose reference, then it almost certainly isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: I see this is a valid answer and I recognice that my opinion is not a SO mainstream, thanks all for sharing other opinions.